# Отправка повторяющихся input

Tags: html, backend

Возник такой вопрос. Я вывожу input(ы) в цикле. Условно так:

```
<form method="GET">
{{for}}
 <input type="text" name="outText">
{{end}}
<input type="submit" value="Отправить"> 
</form>
```

Получается, что количество инпутов может быть от 1 до n.
Каждый сл. инпут будет заноситься новой строкой в БД.
У меня есть несколько вариантов как обработать параметры на сервере.

1. Добавлять в тег name + 1. `name="outText1", name="outText2"`
2. Получать массив одинаковых тегов `name` и перебрать их в цикле.

Какой способ реализации можно назвать правильным? Или может быть я вообще двигаюсь не в том направлении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для множества элементов формы с одинаковым именем используется

```
<input type="text" name="outText[]">
```

тогда в POST-запросе придет массив